# optimizing class construction in c++

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2012, optimization, constructor, move

I have a class:

```
class A
{
    double a;
    map <int, double> b;
    public:
    A():a(0.0){}
    A(const double aa, const map <int, double> & bb): a(aa), b(bb){}
    A(double && aa, map <int, double> && bb):a(aa), b(bb) {} 
};
```

The optimizer (VS2012) shows line `A(a1*b1, std::move(bmap))` takes most of the time.

Am I missing something here that can speed up the object construction? I started learning move constructors only recently, so I am not sure if my move constructor or its usage optimal or not.

Little bit more on the code:
I have

```
 A operator *( double in)
 {
  if(in !=0.0)
    {
     map<int, double> tmp(b); //second bottleneck
     for(auto & itr: tmp)
        tmp.second *= in;
     return A(in * a, std::move(tmp)); //first optimization bottleneck
    }
  return A();
 }
```

Comment: What are you doing with that class? The constructor might be taking most of the time because you are using it (or misusing it, who knows?) heavily...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the culprit of your performance issues, **but you're not actually moving `tmp` into `A::b`**. You need to move `bb` into `A::b`, because `bb` is an lvalue:

```
A(double && aa, map <int, double> && bb):a(aa), b(std::move(bb)) {} 
//                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's a [**minimal example on wandbox**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/18Ir1bqAesZAJ8yt) that illustrates the issue.

Comment: is not supposed to happen on its own since I have `&&`?

Comment: @user6386155: if you have `&&` in the parameter it means that **you're only accepting rvalue references**. Once you get an rvalue reference, it is "bound" to `bb`, which is an lvalue *(i.e. you can say `auto ptr = &bb;`)*. To make `bb` an rvalue again, you need to `std::move` it.

Comment: @user6386155: [**This additional example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/R2EDogSZNEDTbty1) shows that a copy is being made.

Comment: @user6386155: you're welcome. Let me know if it fixes your performance issues :)

Comment: @user6386155: awesome. Don't forget to accept this answer if you feel like it solved your issue. Additionally, you could try different approaches. Depending on your map size, you could simply use an array (and keep track of the used/unused indices), or you could use something like `boost::flat_map`.